# Temporal association rules with arulesSequences with quantities

Tags: r, time-series, data-mining, association-rules

I am trying to mine product-usage sequences for multiple users of online gaming site. I have found the R package [arulesSequences](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arulesSequences/index.html) but am not sure how to fit it to my problem. The data format would be tuples similar to those used in [arulesSequences](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arulesSequences/index.html), but instead of just mentioning products A and B in transactions, I would like to mention the quantities in which those products (games of different types) were bought (played, in my case).

Example:

sequence1 (for uid=1)

```
Date   UID Game1     Game2      Game3     Game4
Jan1    1   125times 0times     0times     0times
Jan2    1   0times   1time      0times     0times
```

Each user would have such a sequence. However, I see that arulesSequences function cspades would only allow to operate with bollean types, e.g. whether each game was actually played on that date:

Example:

sequence1 (for uid=1)

```
Date   UID 
Jan1    1   Game1 Game2
Jan2    1   Game1
Jan3    1   Game2 Game3
```

My goal is to determine rules like "if a user playes Game3 on that date, it causes them to play much more of Game2 one week later".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that arulesSequences is really appropriate in your case, because it essentially focuses on 1-dimensional sequences.

I would suggest a model relating the usage of a game i in time t as a function of the usage of games 1-4 in time t-1, t-2, etc. A regression should be appropriate.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have been so fixated on using association rules (or sequence clustering) with this problem that I have not considered to try other techniques. I have searched through all the packages and haven't found anything. Will try regression.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be best modeled as a time series analysis? The counts for each game form a time series and your goal is to see if you can predict a series either by itself or by using all other series as a predictor.

But each day's count doesn't seem to be independent of the previous day's count which I why I thought a time series was most suitable.